# python argparse: force argument sequence

Tags: python, argparse

I need to force/check the arguments sequence handed over to argparse.
I tried the "try/except" approach but it does not seem to work.

```
import argparse

epilog = '''usage example:'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="add watchit hosts", epilog=epilog)
parser.add_argument('--add', nargs='*', default="-1", metavar="key 'value'")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
try:
    args['add'][0] != 'name'
    args['add'][3] != 'desc'
    args['add'][5] != 'ip'
except:
    print "wrong argument sequence, read the help message!"

print args
print args['add'][1]
print args['add'][3]
print args['add'][5]
```

The following call should raise an error, since name is missing.

`root@lpgaixmgmtlx01:/root>python argparse_test.py --add desc 'aixbuildhost - buildhost - Test(Linz)' ip '172.17.14.37' nagiostmpl 'Enable without Notification' tsm 'AIXBUILDHOST' witnode 'lvgwatchit01t' loc 'loc_gru' devgrp 'hg_aix_lpar' persgrp 'cg_aix'`

```
{'add': ['desc', 'aixbuildhost - buildhost - Test(Linz)', 'ip', '172.17.14.37', 'nagiostmpl', 'Enable without Notification', 'tsm', 'AIXBUILDHOST', 'witnode', 'lvgwatchit01t', 'loc', 'loc_gru', 'devgrp', 'hg_aix_lpar', 'persgrp', 'cg_aix']}
aixbuildhost - buildhost - Test(Linz)
172.17.14.37
Enable without Notification
...and so on
```

Any clever solution to force the arguments sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try/except` works only if the code block in `try` returns an error. With the method you're currently trying to apply, it should be better to use `if` + `sys.exit`:

```
import sys
if args['add'][0] is not 'name' or args['add'][3] is not 'desc' or args['add'][5] is not 'ip':
    parser.error("Wrong argument sequence!")
```

Example:

```
import argparse
import sys

epilog = '''usage example:'''

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="add watchit hosts", epilog=epilog)
parser.add_argument('--add', nargs='*', default="-1", metavar="key 'value'")
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['add'][0] is not 'name' or args['add'][3] is not 'desc' or args['add'][5] is not 'ip':
    parser.error("Wrong argument sequence!")
    # Returns the usage, the error message, and exits (suggested by @hpaulj)

print args
print args['add'][1]
print args['add'][3]
print args['add'][5]
```

Comment: `parser.error("Wrong argument sequence")` will display the `usage`, this message, and then exit.

Comment: Great note @hpaulj, I'll edit that in my answer if you don't mind.